# Recursion, Node js and Asynchronous calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, q

I am trying to get the savePlaces array as the final output so that I can return it in the response. But I am getting success as undefined in function2().
 Why I am not getting the savePlaces as expected. Please provide solution....

```
var saveOverriddenPlaces = function(index, savePlaces) {
    var groupSettingsDAO = new GroupSettingsDAO();
    var deferred = q.defer();
    if (index == savePlaces.length) {
        console.log("-----------------------------deferred--------------------------------", deferred);
        console.log("LAST RETURN -----------------------------" + savePlaces + "----------------------------------------------------", index);
        deferred.resolve(savePlaces);
        return deferred.promise;
    }
    var placeInfo = {
        "id": savePlaces[index].id,
        "groupurl": savePlaces[index].groupurl,
        "sla": savePlaces[index].sla
    };
    if (savePlaces[index]._id) {
        placeInfo._id = savePlaces[index]._id;
        //update the overriden places in the database
        groupSettingsDAO.updateOverriddenPlace(placeInfo)
            //updates the overriden place and sends result in response when successful else logs error
            .then(
                //success
                function(success) {
                    console.log("recursion ============" + index + "=======================");
                    deferred.resolve(saveOverriddenPlaces(++index, savePlaces));

                    return deferred.promise;
                },
                //failure
                function(error) {
                    console.log("PLACES     ERROR ===================================", error);
                });
        // placesWithID.push(value);
    }
    //WITHOUT ids
    else {
        placeInfo._id = guid();
        savePlaces[index]._id = placeInfo._id;
        groupSettingsDAO.saveOverriddenPlace(placeInfo)
            // saves the overridden place and sends the results in response if successful else logs the error
            .then(
                //success
                function(success) {
                    console.log("recursion ============" + index + "=======================");
                    deferred.resolve(saveOverriddenPlaces(++index, savePlaces));
                },
                //failure
                function(error) {
                    console.log("PLACES     ERROR ===================================", error);

                });
    }
}
function2(req, res) {
    saveOverriddenPlaces(0, req.savePlaces).then(function(success) {
        //getting success as undefined 
        res.send({
            "result": success
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using the Q library and groupSettingsDAO is a dao object which has method updateOverriddenPlace() which returns a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the line

```
deferred.resolve(saveOverriddenPlaces(++index, savePlaces));
```

your `saveOverriddenPlaces` function does not (always) return a promise or a value. If a function is asynchronous, it **must always** return a promise.

You can easily do that by adding a `return` before the `groupSettingsDAO.…().then(…)` calls in your conditional statements - as [`then` does return](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) exactly the promise that you want if you `return` a value/prmise from its callback.

However, you should try to avoid the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572). For your base case, use the [`Q` function](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qvalue) to create a fulfilled promise, for everything else just chain `then` calls - no deferreds needed.

```
function saveOverriddenPlaces(index, savePlaces) {
    if (index == savePlaces.length) {
        console.log("LAST RETURN -" + savePlaces + "-", index);
        return Q(savePlaces);
    }
    var groupSettingsDAO = new GroupSettingsDAO();
    var placeInfo = {
        "id": savePlaces[index].id,
        "groupurl": savePlaces[index].groupurl,
        "sla": savePlaces[index].sla
    };
    var promise;
    if (savePlaces[index]._id) {
        placeInfo._id = savePlaces[index]._id;
        promise = groupSettingsDAO.updateOverriddenPlace(placeInfo); //update the overriden places in the database
        // placesWithID.push(value);
    } else { // WITHOUT ids
        placeInfo._id = guid();
        savePlaces[index]._id = placeInfo._id;
        promise = groupSettingsDAO.saveOverriddenPlace(placeInfo) // saves the overridden place
    }
    return promise.then(function(success) {
//  ^^^^^^
        console.log("recursion =" + index + "=" + success);
        return saveOverriddenPlaces(++index, savePlaces));
//      ^^^^^^
    });
}
function2(req, res) {
    saveOverriddenPlaces(0, req.savePlaces).then(function(success) {
        //getting success as undefined 
        res.send({
            "result": success
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("PLACES ERROR =", error);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Bergi. I finally understood where I made my mistake.:-)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `saveOverriddenPlaces` is not returning a value and therefore it is not passed to the `.then` statement in function two. The "solution" is to make sure that `saveOverridenPlaces` returns a Promise that calls resolve with a value that you want to pass to success.

Comment: Thanks for replying but I too understood that the saveOverriddenPlaces is not returning the promise. The problem is I am not able to figure out how I can do that. As I tried returning the array with updated values on the last index value. I read other articles on recursion with node.js using promises but was not able to solve this problem.

Comment: Understood the problem.